# Can Function based views be reused in several apps without duplicating the code?

Tags: django

I have bunch of function based views that have similar functionality

For example create, list, edit view and search  companies and contacts of: Customers ,  Vendors and  Manufactures.

I can reuse the same model with few boolean flags for all 3 of them.
But I was wondering how to deal with view and templates in a best way to avoid code duplications. (currently I am thinking but massive usage of control-H but it doesn't feel right)

(I regret now not using the Class based views but it is too late)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, of course, depends on what actually is different between the models. But if you can abstract your view functions "with a few boolean flags" I would suggest to put them in a central place, probably a common file in your app or project, e.g. `abstract_views.py`.

Then you will only need to dispatch the view functions in a meaningful way:

```
import my_app.abstract_views
from .models import Model1, Model2

def model1_create_view(request):
    abstract_views.create(request, model=Model1)

def model2_create_view(request):
    abstract_views.create(request, model=Model2)
```

In this hypthetical example `create` would be the abstract view function for creating an instance and it would require a parameter `model` with the actual model to operate on.

ADDED:

Alternatively, use boolean flags, as requested:

```
import my_app.abstract_views

def model1_create_view(request):
    abstract_views.create(request, is_customer=True)

def model2_create_view(request):
    abstract_views.create(request, is_vendor=True)
```

When using boolean flags, remember to define what happens if someone is both, a customer and a vendor...

The definition of the abstract view then reads something like:

```
def abstract_view(request, is_customer=False, is_vendor=False):
    context = do_something (is_customer, is_vendor)
    return(render(request, 'app/template.html', context))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. But then how can I add  modifications ? In my case I want to set different Boolean Flag in each case .

So in case of Customer is_customar will be equal True and is_manufacture or is_venor is False. It is not customer who sets it up but it is done in the view depends if you are updating Customer or Vendor.

Comment: @JohnGoldman: Just in the same way. See edited answer above. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot you can do by passing in url parameters to achieve reuse. Your imagination and consistency will help a lot here:

For a simple example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^add-customer/$', create, {'template':'customer.html'}, name='create_customer'),
    url(r'^add-vendor/$', create, {'template':'vendor.html'}, name='create_vendor'),
    url(r'^add-manufacturer/$', create, {'template':'manufacturer.html'}, name='create_manufacturer'),
    ...
```

and the view:

```
def create(request, template):
    #use template as you like, coming from url conf.
    return render(request, template)
    ...
```

That's probably normal code when you think about it. A little more interesting example:

```
from someapp.forms import *
from someapp.models import *
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^customer/$', create, {'template':'customer.html', 'form_class':customer_form}, name='create_customer'),
    url(r'^vendor/$', create, {'template':'vendor.html', 'form_class':vendor_form}, name='create_vendor'),
    url(r'^manufacturer/$', create, {'template':'manufacturer.html', 'form_class':manufacturer_form}, name='create_manufacturer'),
    ...
```

and the view:

```
def create(request, template, form_class):
    #use template as you like, coming from url conf.
    form = form_class()#
    return render(request, template)
    ...
```

Still pretty much normal code. You can get funky and generate the urls dynamically:

In your urls.py:

```
for form_class in (CustomerForm, VendorForm, ManufacturerForm): #model forms
    model = form_class._meta.model
    model_name = model._meta.module_name
    urlpatterns += url(r'^create/$', create, {'template':'%s.html' % model_name, 'form_class':form_class, 'model':model}, name='create_%s' % model_name),
```

and in the view:

```
def create(request, template, form_class, model):
    #use template as you like, coming from url conf.
    form = form_class()#

    return render(request, template)
```

You can pass in pks to models and write codes like:

```
def create(request, form_class, model, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(model, pk=id) if id else None
    edited = True if instance else False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            ...
    else:
        form = form_class(instance=instance)
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form, 'instance': instance})
```

Hopefully you have the stomach for it.